# A heavy loading query not sure what's happened

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, database

I have a SQL query like this, and it takes high amount of loading...

Not sure what is happening here...if anyone could help me with this.

```
SELECT  `posts`.* FROM `posts`  
WHERE `posts`.`type` 
IN ('MySubDomainSitePost') 
AND `posts`.`aasm_state` = 'published' 
AND (published_at <= '2015-05-12 01:01:01') 
AND `posts`.`on_frontpage` = 1
AND `posts`.`is_pinned` = 0 
ORDER BY published_at DESC LIMIT 16
```

Comment: The query itself is very simple - therefore, most probably, the table is really huge, and you do not have any indices on that.

Comment: Yeap! The table is quite large, except `on_frontpage` and `is_pinned` in my posts table, my other attributes have indices on them. So setting index on "all" of the attributes that I'm querying is a better solution?

Comment: firstly, change your `in` to an `=`, since you're only checking one value. second, then, make sure you have a composite index covering `(type, aasm_state, published_at, on_frontpage,is_pinned)`.  that should help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the query performance using `explain select`. Now for large data-set the query will perform very poorly if the columns are not indexed.

From the given query you may need to add the following indexes

```
alter table posts 
add index p_search_idx(type,aasm_state,published_at,on_frontpage,is_pinned);
```

This will boost up the speed of the query.

Make sure to take a backup of the table before applying the index.

And no need to use `IN` in the query it could be as

```
SELECT  `posts`.* FROM `posts`  
WHERE `posts`.`type` = 'MySubDomainSitePost' 
AND `posts`.`aasm_state` = 'published' 
AND (published_at <= '2015-05-12 01:01:01') 
AND `posts`.`on_frontpage` = 1
AND `posts`.`is_pinned` = 0 
ORDER BY published_at DESC LIMIT 16
```

Comment: this answer is my comment. agree with everything.

Comment: Ha looks like we had the same thinking almost at the same time `deja vu`